# Error: sObject type 'Organization' is not supported

Tags: api, permissions

My company runs a SaaS application and we have hundreds of organizations integrated with Salesforce. For one customer in particular we are receiving the following error when attempting to authenticate to the API.

> Error: sObject type 'Organization' is not supported.

On a Salesforce forum someone suggests that `View All Data` permissions are required to access the Organization object. I'm not entirely sure this is accurate.

How are permissions for this object configured?

Comment: Is your app managed package app ?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava it is not. It is a node.js app, and we are OAuth for authentication. Have yo run into this error before on either a managed package or external app?

Comment: Looks like your profile needs View All permission which can be a big deal to provide lot of other permissions to the user .

Answer (score 2):

Users currently need to have "View Setup and Configuration" to see this object

Comment: Is this still the case? Is there no simpler way to do it for users who don't need that access? For my app, we just want to know if an org is a sandbox or not when logged in as a non-privileged user who does not have Setup access.